# Incrementing pointer to pointer by one byte

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 int a = 5;
 int *p = &a;
 int **pp = &p;

 char **cp = (char **)pp;  
 cp++;                    // This still moves 8 bytes
 return 0;
}
```

Since the size of a pointer is 64 bits on 64 bit machines, doing a `pp++` will always move 8 bytes. Is there a way to make it move only 1 byte?

Comment: What evidence do you have that `pp++` "will always move 8 bytes"?

Comment: You are actually incrementing a `char *`, which is larger than 1 byte.  And you cannot increment something by a fraction of its size.

Comment: Dare we ask *why* you want to do this?

Comment: @Beta experimenting with C

Comment: You can do this `cp = ((uint64_t)cp) + 1` if you want to do it at all cost assuming the pointer size 8 byte in your machine.

Comment: @Eraklon But you can't really do anything with that value.  It no longer points to a pointer of any type, and dereferencing it is therefore undefined behavior.  (And pedantically, `uintptr_t` should be used instead of `uint64_t` if you're going to break the rules that way.)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Well obviously it is pointless to do this, but I am just stating how it could be done. The `uintptr_t` is a good suggestion though, thanks!

Comment: It is not true that “the size of a pointer is 64 bits on 64 bit machines.” The size of a pointer is determined by the C implementation, not by the machine it executes on. I have worked with a C implementation that targeted 64-bit machines but used 32-bit pointers.

Comment: The phrasing ”doing a `pp++` will always move 8 bytes” is not good. “Moving eight bytes” generally means copying the values of eight bytes from one location to another. A better phrasing would be “executing `pp++` adjusts `pp` to point to an address eight bytes greater.”

Comment: They don't always move eight bytes

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make it move only 1 byte?

Maybe.

All object pointers can be converted to `void *` and since `char *` has the same representation, to `char *`.  `++` increments a `char *` by 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
 int a = 5;
 int *p = &a;
 int **pp = &p;
 char **cp = (char **)pp;  

 char *character_pointer = (char *) cp;
 character_pointer++; // Increment by 1
```

Now is the tricky part.  Can that incremented pointer convert back to a `char **`.  C allows that unless

> If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.  C17dr § 6.3.2.2 7

```
 cp = (char **) character_pointer;
 return 0;
}
```

Reading `*cp` can readily cause undefined behavior as `cp` does not certainly point to a valid `char *`.  Unclear as to OP's goal at this point.

Answer (score 0):

C is not assembly. What you are trying to do is **undefined behavior**, and **compiler might not do what you ask**, and **the program might do anything**, including possibly what you think it should do if C were just "assembly" with different syntax.

That being said, you can do this:

```c
 int a = 5;
 int *p = &a;
 int **pp = &p;
 uintptr_t temp;
 memcpy(&temp, &pp, sizeof temp);
 temp++;
 memcpy(&pp, &temp, sizeof temp);
```

Above code is likely to do what you want, even though that last `memcpy` already triggers undefined behavior, because it copies invalid value to a pointer (that is enough for it to be UB). Actually using `pp`, which now has invalid value, has increasing chance of messing things up.

---

To understand why having any UB is indeed UB: compiler is free to decide that the effect of the code, which can be proven to have UB, is nothing, or is never reached. So if that last `memcpy` is inside `if`, and compiler can prove UB occurs if condition is true, it may just assume condition is never true and optimize whole `if` away. Presumably C programmer knows to write their condition so that it would never result in UB, so this optimization can be made at compile time already.

Yeah, it is a bit crazy. C is not just assembly with different syntax!

Answer (score 0):

*Incrementing pointer to pointer by one byte*

If you find an implementation where the size of a pointer to pointer variable contains only 8 bits, (i.e. one that uses 1 byte addressing, [btw, very unlikely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40978974/645128)),  then it will be doable, and only then would it be safe to do so.  Otherwise it would not be considered a practical or safe thing to do.

For an implementation that uses 64 bit addressing, 64 bits are needed to represent each *natural* pointer location.  Note however though _[t]he smallest incremental change is *[available as a by-product of]* the alignment needs of the referenced type. For performance, this often matches the width of the ref type, yet systems can allow less._ (per @Chux in comments) but de-referencing these locations could, and likely would lead to undefined behavior.

And in this statement

```
 char **cp = (char **)pp; //where pp is defined as int **
```

the cast, although allowing a compile without complaining, is simply masking a problem.  With the exception of `void *`, pointer variables are created using the same base type of the object they are to point to for the reason that the `sizeof` different types can be different, so the pointers designed to point to a particular type can represent its locations accurately.

It is also important to note the following:

```
            sizeof char ** == sizeof char * == sizeof char *** !!= sizeof char`   
     32bit  4 bytes           4 bytes            4 bytes             1 byte 
     64bit  8 bytes           8 bytes            8 bytes             1 byte  

            sizeof int ** == sizeof int * == sizeof int *** !!= sizeof int`   
     32bit  4 bytes           4 bytes            4 bytes             4 bytes (typically)
     64bit  8 bytes           8 bytes            8 bytes             4 bytes (typically)
```

So, unlike the `type` of a pointer, its *size* has little to do with it's ability to *point* to a location containing an object that is *smaller*, or even *larger* in size than the pointer used to point to it.

The purpose of a pointer ( eg `char *` ) is to store an address to an object of the same base type, in this case `char`.  If targeting 32bit addressing, then the size of the pointer indicates it can point to `4,294,967,296` different locations (or if 64 bits to `18,446,744,073,709,551,616` locations.) and because in this case it is designed to point to `char`, each address differs by one byte.

But this really has nothing to do with your observation that when you increment a `pointer to pointer to char` that you see `8 bytes`, and not `1 byte`.  It simply has to do with the fact that pointers, in 64bit addressing, require `8 bytes` of space, thus the successive printf statements below will always show an increment of `8 bytes` between the 1st and 2nd calls:

```
 char **cp = (char **)pp; 
 size_t size = sizeof(cp);
 printf("address of cp before increment: %p\n", cp);
 cp++;                    // This still moves 8 bytes
 printf("address of cp after increment: %p\n", cp);
 return 0;
```

Comment: "For an implementation that uses 64 bit addressing, 64 bits are needed to represent each pointer location, therefore the smallest incremental change in location will be 8 bytes." Not quite.  The smallest incremental change is a requirement of the alignment needs of the referenced type.  For performance, this often matches the width of the ref type, yet systems can allow less.

Comment: Of course dereferencing an invalid pointer is UB.  My comment was on the valid _locations_ of a pointer, not their value  - pointers are not specified by C to exist on N-byte boundaries (in a system with N-byte pointers).

Comment: No, I think you are on the right track, just some of the rational is off a bit.  It is curious as to _why_ OP wants to do this.  Sound like [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Actually there are implementations where a pointer has a size of 1 byte. One of them are C compilers for the 8051.

Comment: @thebusybee - Per the [conversation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40978974/645128), I am no longer certain that your claim is really watertight. Can you substantiate it with an actual example of a single byte pointer for a C compiler for the 8051? ( I still appreciate your comment. )

Comment: I am thinking of pointers to variables in the 8051's DATA and PDATA memory sections. Those sections are addressed by 8 bits only, so their pointers are only 1 byte wide. (Side note: PDATA is a paged view into the 64KiB XDATA section, which normally needs 16-bit addresses.) Well, you could say, this is non-conformance, because one seems to have to use a special keyword like `__data`. But you can call the compiler with an option to place all variables in DATA or PDATA by default. The source is clean, then, like `char *p;`.

Comment: Actually, Keil C51 supports several pointer types, ranging from 1 to 3 bytes width. The "bigger" derivatives even may use 4 bytes, but I'm talking about the generic 8-bit processor of the 8051.